# Unable to add Schemas (xsd) in XML setting

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, dtd

I am trying to *add the xsd file (schema)* for the XML in IntelliJ but when I select any file, the **add button gets disabled**.

For adding schema, I followed following path:

> > File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Schemas and DTDs - (+) button under 'External Schemas and DTDs' section

Please find the attached image below.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI field on the top of the dialog is empty. Provide it and the OK button will become enabled.

Comment: Thank you Ivaylo for your kind reply. 

Interestingly, I was expecting when I am having the _.xsd_ file locally in my system. There is no need to enter the URI.

When I added URI and select the file, it works for me. Also, I have updated the image, so that in future someone refer to this answer get the updated information.

So, the concluding point is, first we can select file from given list as well as add the URI of this.

Thanks again, I appreciate your response of this :-)